# rails aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, capistrano

basically i'm trying to deploy rails application through capistrano to ec2 instance and when i ran cap production reploy i get this error when cap tries to deploy db:migrate rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
here is my code of deploy.rb

```
lock "3.8.1"

set :application, "airstage"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:hswasim71/airstage-api.git"
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log',
                                               'tmp/pids',
                                               'tmp/cache',
                                               'tmp/sockets',
                                               'vendor/bundle')
# set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/sidekiq.yml', '.env')
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/sidekiq.yml }
set :rails_env, :production
set :migration_role, :app
# set :puma_init_active_record, true
# set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/config/puma.rb"
set :format, :airbrussh
set :sidekiq_config, -> { File.join(shared_path, 'config', 'sidekiq.yml') }

namespace :deploy do
    task :seed do
        on primary fetch(:migration_role) do
            within release_path do
            with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env)  do
                execute :rake, 'db:seed'
            end
            end
        end
    end
    before 'check:linked_files', 'puma:config'
end
# new relic implementation
# after "deploy:updated", "newrelic:notice_deployment"
after 'deploy:finished', 'puma:restart'
```

and here is my capfile

````
``` # new relic implementation
# require 'new_relic/recipes'

require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
require "capistrano/rvm"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require 'whenever/capistrano'
require "capistrano/nginx"
require 'capistrano/puma'
require "capistrano/puma/nginx"
require "capistrano/upload-config"
require 'capistrano/sidekiq'
# require 'capistrano/rails/dotenv'
# install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Jungle
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Workers
# install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Monit
# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r } ```
````

and here is the trace

```
00:28 bundler:install
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.7.4 do bundle install --path /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --qui…
    ✔ 01 deploy@18.185.53.119 4.709s
00:32 deploy:migrate
      [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
00:33 deploy:migrating
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.7.4 do bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword p…
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword p…
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword p…
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword p…
      01 DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original …
      01 DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original …
      01 rake aborted!
      01 NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/releases/20220929195733/config/environments/production.rb:62:in `block in <top (required)>'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `configure'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/releases/20220929195733/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in requir…
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/releases/20220929195733/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in requir…
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
      01 /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
      01 Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
      01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
#<Thread:0x000055657065b2f8 /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    13: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    12: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
    11: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
    10: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capistrano-rails-1.2.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     9: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `within'
     8: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capistrano-rails-1.2.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:24:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     7: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:93:in `with'
     6: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capistrano-rails-1.2.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:25:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     5: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:74:in `execute'
     4: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
     3: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
     2: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
     1: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:165:in `execute_command'
/home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:100:in `exit_status=': rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from require at /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81)
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from require at /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81)
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/home/deploy/airstage/releases/20220929195733/config/environments/production.rb:62:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `configure'
/home/deploy/airstage/releases/20220929195733/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/deploy/airstage/releases/20220929195733/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
    1: from /home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@18.185.53.119: rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: /home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
/home/deploy/airstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
```

And here is my production.rb file

```
server "18.185.53.119", user: "deploy", roles: %w{app db web}, primary: true
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/airstage'
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/config/puma.rb"
set :puma_threads, [12, 32]
set :puma_workers, 4
set :branch, :master
set :puma_env, 'production'
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.7.4'
# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
# You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
# limited set of options, consult the Net::SSH documentation.
# http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start
#
# Global options
# --------------
# server '3.122.178.36', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
set :ssh_options, {
    keys: %w[/home/hs/Downloads/my_key1.pem],
    forward_agent: true,
    # auth_methods: %w[/home/hs/.ssh/id_rsa.pub]
}
```

Comment: And where that error is happening? please add the complete error stacktrace to your question

Comment: Show `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: added production.rb this error comes when i  run the command cap production deploy